# How can I query using Entity Framework with an alpha-numeric comparison?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I make a query using Entity Framework and LINQ on a alphanumeric comparison only? I have a database table with an AccountNumber field which contains special characters, so an example account number might look like this:  `803-2234502-345`. But the account number that I'm given to search by will not have the special characters: `8032234502345`

```
    string accountNumber = "8032234502345";
    Provider provider = dbContext.Providers.Where(p => p.AccountNumber == accountNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

I've tried adding a `Regex.Replace` to both sides of the comparison, but I get an exception:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are the account numbers in the database all in a specific and uniformed format?

Comment: No, I wish they were, otherwise this would be much easier  :-(

Comment: You are aware that when you actually load the entities from the database using the ToList extension method, you will then have all the string manipulation methods available? This approach would however force you to load at least the accountnumbers and primary keys in memory for all records.

Comment: You can't just normalise your account numbers in the db I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Linq to Entities so can only use what functions map through to SQL in the enities mappers. You could either change the functions you are using to map properly to SQL (though I suspect with Regex you won't be-able to do that - would have to be a more manual comparison), or (as @Dabblernl mentioned in the comments) load your Providers (or a subset of providers) into a list / or enumerable, and then run the regex over that.

So something like:

```
Provider provider = dbContext.Providers.Where(p => p != null && p != "").ToList()
.Where(p => *Do regex comparison here*).FirstOrDefault();
```

Possible mappings to SQL are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

Comment: There actually is a Replace mapping for String.Replace (in stead of Regex.Replace)

Comment: Yes, I think @MaxOctane could manage something with basic string functions, but not with Regex.

Comment: I normally would not accept this answer because pulling all records from the database is inefficient. However given how often this query will run and how many records I have in the database, this should work fine. Thanks for your help.